# Is there an object/grob that supports both line breaks and partial bolding

Tags: r, text

Rather self explanatory.

I know that plotmath can do the partial bolding part using the bold function in the expression but is there anything that functionality that also supports line breaks/other control characters?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Your question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

`splitTextGrob()` in [`RGraphics`](https://cran.fhcrc.org/web/packages/RGraphics/index.html) can do line breaks on a text string